# what is the php curl equalent to commandline curl?

Tags: php, curl

I've tested this command with curl in the command prompt and it works and does what I want it to do.

```
curl -T filetoupload.tmp http://example.com -H "Accept: text/html" -H "Content-type: appliction/pdf" > filename.htm
```

I've then tried to express this in php(I run PHP v5.5) and wrote this code, but the remote server doesn't like it so it obviously isn't doing the same thing.

```
$ch = curl_init("http://example.com"); 
$cfile = curl_file_create('filetoupload.tmp', 'application/pdf', 'filename');
$data['file'] = $cfile;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-type: application/pdf',
  'Accept: text/html'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curl -T filetoupload.tmp` uploads the file as the RAW post body.  Your PHP code is sending the file with headers, like you were posting a form with `multipart/form-data`.

You need to set the *raw* post body in your PHP code.  Also, it looks like [`curl -T`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-T) uses `PUT` instead of `POST`.

```
$ch = curl_init("http://example.com"); 
$file = fopen('filetoupload.tmp', 'r');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize('filetoupload.tmp'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-type: application/pdf',
  'Accept: text/html'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: That sounds reasonable. However I think I might have something else wrong too and that is causing an error. When using the commandline curl to http://localhost:9998/tika it just works but when I use it with curl_init("http://localhost:9998/tika") in php the remote server gives the warning: `WARNING: No operation matching request path "/tika" is found, Relative Path: /` how is curl_init("url") different, and how to make it work?

Comment: I don't know what to tell ya.  What server software are you using at `localhost:9998`?

Comment: I've never used that nor even know what it is.  So I don't know what to tell ya.  EDIT: Though it looks like you might need to use `PUT` instead of `POST`.  I think `-T` might use `PUT`.  Try the updated code in my answer (change `CURLOPT_POST` to `CURLOPT_PUT`).

Comment: Given that the commandline curl works as I intend to use it how to write it to work identically in php? the remote server shouldn't be able to tell the difference between the two if done correctly

Comment: I think you have pointed me on the right track, there are still errors. I will get back to you tomorrow if I find it related to my original question, otherwise I will mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Well, glad I was able to help, somewhat :-)

Comment: I edited your answer to use CURLOPT_INFILE and CURLOPT_INFILESIZE instead of CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS like in the manual for CURLOPT_PUT http://se1.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php